# Функция imagecopy бьет цвета при наложении

Tags: php

Вопрос в следующем: читаю статью [Фотомонтажим на PHP](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_999.html). Но пример автора почему-то не работает, ломает почему-то цвета:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/png");

$res = imagecreate(120,120); 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("photo.jpg");
$mask = imagecreatefrompng("border.png"); 
$logo = imagecreatefrompng("logo.png");

$green = imagecolorallocate($res,136,203,44);

imagecopyresized ($res,$img,
 0,0,
 0,0,
 120,120,
 imagesx($img),imagesy($img));
imagecopy ($res,$logo,60,110,0,0,60,12);

/*int imagecopy (куда накладываем, что накладываем, куда вставляем У, куда вставляем Х, точка откуда начинаем копировать лого Х, точка откуда начинаем копировать лого У, ширина лого, высота лого)*/

imagecopy ($res,$mask,0,0,0,0,120,120);

$trans = imagecolorat($res,0,0);
imagecolortransparent($res,$trans);

imagepng($res);

?>
```

Почему так происходит? В примере автора на сайте все нормально. Скачал его же пример, цвета даже с его примером бьются. В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала последние два символа в первой строке убери, а там видно будет. =)

UPD:
вместо

```
$res = imagecreate(120,120);
```

должно быть

```
$res = imagecreatetruecolor(120,120);
```

И еще один момент, в качестве бонуса =) Чтобы  качество при уменьшении картинки было лучше, нужно вместо

```
imagecopyresized ($res,$img,
```

написать

```
imagecopyresampled ($res,$img,
```

Comment: Да нет... это я тупанул... просто экспериментов много было уже. Но это был бы полный пипец, если бы из за закомменченного не работало))) причина не в этом.

Comment: обновил ответ, вот тут можно посмотреть разницу при сжатии, угловатости проходят и меньше пикселявость
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1318021032-clip-13kb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) вместо imagecreate().